# The probability that $\text{'O'}$ remain between $\text{'G'}$ in a randomly selected word, is

Tags: probability

> Consider the word $\text{GOOGLE}$. Among all the $6$ letter word that are formed using the letter
>
> of the word $\text{GOOGLE}$ , a word is randomly Selected.
>
> The probability that $\text{'O'}$ remain between $\text{'G'}$ in a randomly selected word, is

Attempt: Total arrangement of word $\text{GOOGLE}$ is $\displaystyle \frac{6!}{2!\cdot 2!}$

Arrangement of word in which $\text{'O'}$ remain between $\text{'G'}$ is

$\text{G_ _G_ _}$ or $\text{_G_ _ G_}$ or $\text{_ _G_ _E}$ .

So total favourable  arrangements $ \displaystyle  \frac{4!}{2!}+\frac{4!}{2!}+\frac{4!}{2!} = 18$

but in answer all favourable given as $30$

could some help me how to solve it, thanks

Comment: What about the arrangements G _ _ _ G_, G _ _ _ _ G?

Comment: As an alternate approach:  Consider arrangements of the four letters $O,O, G, G$.  There are $\binom 64=15$ ways to place the four and only one way to arrange them that has the form you want.  Then there are two ways to place the $L,E$ in the remaining slots.  Thus the answer is $\binom 64 \times 2=15\times 2 = 30$.